# bootstrap icons not being displayed in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm using bootstrap, very new to it all. On my production side of things my icons are appearing fine, under safari and chrome they appear fine also. The code I use to link the icons to appear is as follows:

```
<a href="/Admin/God/Admin.aspx" class="button rectangular"><i class="icon-group icon-large"></i><span class="button-text">Users</span></a>
```

The site is iskittle.co.uk if you view it other apart from IE the icons appear. I'm somewhat stumped...I guess it will have something to do with how IE is handling the how the CSS gets the images.

Like I said I am new to this but I think it gets the icons from a larger image http://iskittle.co.uk/images/icons/glyphicons-halflings-white.png

Why would chrome and safari be able to work out how to do this but no IE...any ideas/help would be great, I have done a lot of searching on the net but cant seem to a straight forward answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font isn't loading as IE is unable to download the `.woff` file. Internet Explorer is much more picky about permissions to use fonts. To fix it, check:

1. Make sure the file exists on the server and is accessible from `http://iskittle.co.uk/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff`.
2. If it is already there make sure your IIS server is set up correctly to deploy woff files. In your `web.config`, make sure the following exists:

   ```
   <staticContent>
         <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
   </staticContent>
   ```

Comment: Its works! You just saved me about 10 years of my life because thats how long it would have taken me to figure that out, can't thank you enough :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS File look for this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
  src: url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot") format("eot"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

**Change this part:**

```
src: url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot") format("eot"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format("svg");
```

**To this:**

```
src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
```